# Почему значение выдается в rgb?

Tags: jquery, css

```js
let col = $('.header-center').css('background-color');
console.log(typeof col, col);
```

```css
.header-center {
  background-color: #955826
}

.header-center {
  height:100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="header-center"></div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
значение в css в шестнадцатеричном коде

как получить значение в шестнадцатеричном коде?

Answer (score 2):

```js
let col = $('.header-center').css('background-color');
console.log(typeof col, col, eval(col));

function rgb(r, g, b) {
  function toHex(a) {
    return ((a < 16)? "0" : "") + a.toString(16);
  }

  return "#" + toHex(r) + toHex(g) + toHex(b);
}
```

```css
.header-center {
  background-color: #955826
}

.header-center {
  height:100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="header-center"></div>
```